# a question about lint tool in vscode-go plugin

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, plugins

Now lint tool can only be set to staticcheck, golint, golangci-lint, revive in vscode-go plugin, is it allowed that Lint Tool can be set to my customized lint tool?

Comment: can you specify which lint tool you need to be setup.